# Vim with VOoM and LaTeX-Suite plugins result in odd key mapping behavior

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, latex-suite

I use latex-suite to write `.tex` files. To easily switch between default compiler (pdflatex) and xelatex I have the following script in my `_vimrc` file.

```
function SetXeLaTeX()
    let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'xelatex --interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -src-specials $*'
endfunction
map <Leader>lx :<C-U>call SetXeLaTeX()<CR>
```

So in Vim, I can normally use `\lx` to call `SetLaTeX()` function. And actually I have similar scripts for other key-bindings such as `\lp` for pdflatex and `\la` for arara.

Everything works just fine until `Voom` outline command is called.

After runnig the command `:Voom latex` which generates Voom outline file `.tex_VOOM1` alongside the `.tex` file, all these key mappings (`\lx`, `\lp` and `\la`) start behaving oddly:

**They no longer calls my custom functions, instead they all trigger character-wise Visual mode.**

It seems somehow `Voom` remapped all my commands. And I cannot over-ride it by running

```
:map <Leader>lx :<C-U>call SetXeLaTeX()<CR>
```

command in Vim's current session.

Can anybody tell me what is exactly wrong? How to fix this oddity?

**Update**

Strangely enough, I discovered that if I remove the `<C-U>` key in custom functions, no misbehavior is encountered. After this tweak, the `\lx` command will work as expected.

Comment: Voom? What is this command for?

Comment: @hawk `:Voom` is defined by `VOoM` plugin to create two-pane outline. See details: [link](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2657)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Apparently, Voom defines a `<C-u>` mapping, and your `:map` commands use that, and it's wreaking havoc on them.

Comment: Thank you very much. You finally solved my problem! Sooner or later, I'd better learn some vimscripts. I'm sorry that I cannot upvote your answer because of insufficient reputation points...